# Reload Vaadin Portlet on page refresh

Tags: java, vaadin, page-refresh

I've got a basic Vaadin Portlet deployed on a Tomcat Server. The page consists of a few basic form elements. Ie. TextFields & ComboBoxes.

If I enter text into the fields / make a selection on the combo. When I press F5 when I have the page open in a browser, it retains all the data on the page.

Is there a way to force Vaadin to rebuild on page refresh?

Comment: Have you tried the `?restartApplication` parameter as stated in the docs https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/application/application-lifecycle.html ?

Comment: @AxelMeier I don't know how well that works for a production environment

Comment: I see. I think I misunderstood the question. I thought the question was to look for a way to force a page refresh while developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've achieved this in the past using the [PortletListener](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinPortletSession.PortletListener.html) interface that Vaadin offers you.

Depending on how you've built your page. This basic example may help you:

```
public class MyUI extends UI implements PortletListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1708010797368609962L;
    private VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        VaadinPortletSession session = (VaadinPortletSession) VaadinPortletSession.getCurrent();
        session.addPortletListener(this);
        content.addComponent(new MyCustomScreen());
        setContent(content);
    }

    private void reloadPage() {
        content.removeAllComponents();
        content.addComponent(new MyCustomScreen());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, UI uI) {
        accessSynchronously(this::reloadPage);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleActionRequest(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response, UI uI) {
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEventRequest(EventRequest request, EventResponse response, UI uI) {
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResourceRequest(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response, UI uI) {
    }       
}
```

In short, you'll enter the handleRenderRequest method when you hit F5. So you can use your own custom method to re-build the page to your needs.

I hope this helps.